# How do I use a style when putting a textView into code manually in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml, textview

I'm trying to make my game work in all layouts equally well, and in order to facilitate this, I'm using styles which are size dependent. The problem is, this breaks down with the function that I've coded directly, due to its high repetitiveness. So, what can I do to apply one of my styles to these text views that I'm creating in code?

Sample Style code:

```
<style name="medText">
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Sample program code:

```
TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
TableLayout tlayout=new TableLayout(this);
text1.setText(R.string.name);
row.addView(text1);
text2.setText(R.string.level);
row.addView(text2);
text3.setText(R.string.score);
row.addView(text3);
tlayout.addView(row);
```

I loop through re-creating these TextViews a number of times, with the later ones containing variable input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
TableRow row=new TableRow(this);
TableLayout tlayout=new TableLayout(this);
text1.setText(R.string.name);
text1.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.medText);
row.addView(text1);
text2.setText(R.string.level);
text2.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.medText);
row.addView(text2);
text3.setText(R.string.score);
text3.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.medText);
row.addView(text3);
tlayout.addView(row);
```

Let me know if it works: never used the text appearance functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To set style in TextView

If you have declared your TextView in xml in that xml you have to pass `style="@style/medText"`

### Example

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:text="@string/menu_legal_termsandcondition"
 android:padding="3dip" 
 style="@style/medText"
 android:layout_weight="2"/>
```

If you have created TextView dynamically then you have to use `text1.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.medText);` in your java code

Thanks
Deepak